# Why is the @ symbol added in front of the string when defining ADO.NET connection strings?

Tags: ado.net

For eg.

```
public string conString =@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=..\\..\\PersonDatabase.mdb";
```

I don't understand its use.What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` creates a verbatim string literal, which ignores `\` characters.

It means you don't need to write `\\` in file paths.  (which means your example is wrong)